# Pycharm error in one project and not the other

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, pycharm

I am running PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.3 and having this strange problem where I would run a file in one project and it would produce an error but run the same file in another project and it would produce no error. I have tried figuring out what is causing the problem but to no avail. I have discovered that any file with an import, in the first project (The one that gives me an error) would always get the error but a file without any imports works fine. This is the same whether the code after is correct or not. If someone could please help me with this problem as I could have missed something simple it would be much appreciated.

Code used in both projects:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import RecommendationForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '777'


@app.route('/')
def home():
    form = RecommendationForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Screenshot of project producing error:
[Pycharm project with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAO7A.png)

Screenshot of project working correctly:
[Diffrent Pycharm project with the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avlxA.png)

The error tends to generally look the same with a few variations. Here is an example running different code but in the first project.

[Diffrent code run in the error producing project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0rGL.png)

[The rest of the error logs from the above example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wfYN.png)

Comment: You are using imap module to connect to somewhere but in one case you provide wrong credentials.

Comment: @mx0 Yes I was but I didn't have that file running nor was I calling it. I even removed that code and it didn't fix anything. Upon further inspection, it seems that every time I run a file with an import (in the project that gives me an error) I get the error but running a file without any imports works fine.

Comment: Try removing any `pyc` files if you have them in project folder.

Comment: @mx0 I have to apologize because although I couldn't tell what exact files you wanted me to remove I moved over all my python files to the second project till I could isolate the file causing the problem. It turns out it was the file using the `imaplib`  module even though I commented out all the code. Do you know why this is the case?